# When do you use the render function in vue?

Tags: vue.js

When would be a good use case for using the render function in Vue.js and when would you use a template?  Are there technical considerations or is it just about coding style?

Answer (score 1):

> Vue recommends using templates to build your HTML in the vast majority
> of cases. There are situations however, where you really need the full
> programmatic power of JavaScript. That’s where you can use the render
> function, a closer-to-the-compiler alternative to templates.

Please refer [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) for details explanation.

Comment: It seems like the germane part of the answer is in describing the "situations...where you need the full programming power of JavaScript".  What are those?  One is when the tags and structure (rather than their attributes and content) are very conditionally based on the values of props.

Comment: When you have mixins with create nodes functions youll invoke them in render functions